# I want to pass an argument into a variable?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I am very new to the Linux environment, and I am stuck with a situation.
What I want to do is to pass the command `test -s $testFile` to a variable, like, say "tes"
Example:

```
tes="test -s $testFile"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the command you're trying returns specific data, you could use:

```bash
test = "$(test -s $testFile)"
```

When you use `$()`, you're telling the command line to execute the function passed in a subshell, get the result and print back on the other terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo [string you want to output].
echo [object that may or may not turn into a string].
```

Careful with the '$', as noted above.